# Как отключить слайдинг

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем день добрый. Использую ViewPager и TabLayout в связке. Есть три фрагмента которые переключаются с помощью TabLayout. Есть необходимость отключить возможность перелистывания первого фрагмента. Что бы первый фрагмент переключался только нажатием на TabLayout.

вот кусочек кода где все инициализируется думаю именно тут и должно отключаться но не понимаю как отключить

```
public void myTabsAll()
    {
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        tabsPagerFragment adapter = new tabsPagerFragment(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabl);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    }
```

Comment: тоесть, например, вот я на втором слайде. Я могу свайпнуть на первый, но обратно уже не могу свайпом, только по табу?

Comment: @Flippy Да именно так вы меня правильно поняли

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создаете кастомный `ViewPager` с методом `setEnableSwipe` для блокировки/разблокировки свайпа

```
public class DisableSwipeViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean enableSwipe;

    public DisableSwipeViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DisableSwipeViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        enableSwipe = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return enableSwipe && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return enableSwipe && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setEnableSwipe(boolean enableSwipe) {
        this.enableSwipe = enableSwipe;
    }
}
```

Затем указываете его в разметке:

```
<com.example.myapplication.adapter.DisableSwipeViewPager
    android:layout_width..........
/>
```

Находите так же по id

```
DisableSwipeViewPager vp = (DisableSwipeViewPager) findViewById(R.id.disableSwipeVP);
```

И ставите слушатель на переключение слайдов, чтобы при открытии первого слайда свайп выключался, иначе включался

```
vp.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        vp.setEnableSwipe(position > 0);
    }
});
```

При желании можно добавить установку `OnPageChangeListener` прямо в кастомный `ViewPager`

Comment: К сожалению почему то не удается запустить пример. Приложение крашится. Сначала ругалось на функцию OnPageChangeListener() требовало следующий вид ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() исправил но потом ругаться начало java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.Main2Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to com.example.myapplication.adapter.DisableSwipeViewPager

Comment: @alexsis, ответ обновил

Answer (score 0):

Для ViewPager2 используйте параметр в xml:

```
app:userInputEnabled="@{false}"
```